# Why does ‘next’ make a difference with awk

Tags: shell, awk

The values of Avg are totally different when I add "next" to the awk expression.

- without next

  ```
  seq 1 1 100 | awk '
  NR==1 {
    min = max = $1;
  }
  {
    min = $1 < min ? $1 : min;
    max = $1 > max ? $1 : max;
    total += $1
  }
  END {
    print "Min :",min,"Max :",max,"Avg :",total/NR,"Sum :",total
  }'
  ```

**Avg : 50.5 Sum : 5050**

- with next

  ```
  seq 1 1 100 | awk '
  NR == 1 {
    min = max = $1;
    next;
  }
  {
    min = $1 < min ? $1 : min;
    max = $1 > max ? $1 : max;
    total+= $1
  }
  END {
    print "Min :",min,"Max :",max,"Avg: ",total/NR,"Sum :",total
  }'
  ```

**Avg : 50.49 Sum : 5049**

I don't understand how it happens.And I'll be appreciated if anyone can explain it to me.

Comment: Triple-backticks for multiline quoting are a github extension to Markdown -- they don't work in the standard version used here. Use only four-space indents, as created by the `{}` button, for that purpose.

Comment: That said, `next` tells `awk` to do no further work no the current line. Its impact on your statistics should thus be obvious: The version with  `next` *skips* the updates to `min`, `max` and `total` for the first line; the other does not.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks your advise, I'll try and make it clean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `next` terminates processing of that line of input, and thus prevents the second block (the one with no condition, which thus otherwise runs for *every* line of input) from being run for that line.

Thus, it prevents `total` from being initialized to the value of line 1, and causes your `total` value to be one too low (when your input is from `seq` and the first line contains only `1`).

If you want the `next`, then you need to initialize `total` in that block to avoid throwing off your results:

```
NR==1 {
  min = max = total = $1
  next
}
```

Comment: Thank a lot.And I just remove `NR==1`，using `{min=max=total=0;next}`，and it turn out to be `Min : 0 Max : 0 Avg : 0 Sum : 0`,all values are 0,can you explain it if  it is convenient to you

Comment: oops,I see,when I remove `NR==1`,it skips to the block after END.And I set the initial value of min,max,total to 0,so all of the value is 0 in the end

Comment: oops,I see,when I remove `NR==1`,The next terminates processing of input,and thus prevents the second block from being run for every line,makes it skips to the block after END.And I set the initial value of min,max,total to 0 before,so all of the value is 0 in the end

@CharlesDuffy, is my analysis right?

Comment: `NR==1` is a condition telling that block to be run only for the first line. When you remove the condition, the first block runs for *every* line, so the second block is skipped for the entire file.